# Finding the largest number in a sequence of numbers in a SQL database

Tags: sql

Suppose I have a SQL database in which a column could look something like this

```
Numbers
-------
1
1
2
3
4
4
```

Is it possible to create a single SQL query that simply grabs the largest number, which in this case would be `4`? Or would I have to query every single number, put them in some sort of list in an external program, and write an algorithm to find the largest one?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use can use the MAX Aggregate function. Since your table only has one column it would look like

```
SELECT MAX(NUMBERS) n from yourtable
```

depending on your backend you could also put into a variable. For example in SQL Server

```
Declare @TheMax int
SELECT @TheMax = MAX(NUMBERS) 
FROM yourTable
```

[Here's a working example](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/13086/) on data.stackexchange.com

If you also wanted the Max Per somthing you'd need a group by

For example this [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/107113/) on Data.SE gives the max score per tag

```
SELECT 
      tagname, max(score) 
FROM 
   posts p
   INNER JOIN postTags pt
   ON p.id = pt.postId
   INNER JOIN tags t
   ON pt.tagid = t.id 
GROUP BY 
   tagname ​
```

Answer (score 5):

When `x` is your column name then:

```
SELECT MAX(x) FROM numbers
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work on most SQL servers.

```
Select Max(Number) From Table
```